# Case Status new picklist value deployment error through metadata api

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, ant

We are trying to deploy some new picklist values on the Case object, on the standard Status field. One of them is the value "On-Hold" included on a new Support process, called "Support" which we are also trying to deploy through the metadata api.

This is part of our Case object metadata where the support process is described:

```
<businessProcesses>
    <fullName>Support</fullName>
    <description>Case process for supporting the salesforce application.</description>
    <isActive>true</isActive>
    <values>
        <fullName>Closed</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>In Progress</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>New</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>On-Hold</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>Reopened</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>Triaged</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>Working</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
</businessProcesses>
```

And these are the parts of our package.xml file:

```
<types>
    <members>Case.Master</members>
    <members>Case.Support</members>
    <members>Case.vlocity_ins__Vlocity Support Process</members>
    <members>Lead.Broker Onboarding</members>
    <members>Opportunity.vlocity_ins__Vlocity Sales Process</members>
    <name>BusinessProcess</name>
</types>
```

...

```
    <members>Case.Solution__c</members>
    <members>Case.SourceId</members>
    <members>Case.Stakeholder_Group__c</members>
    <members>Case.Status</members>
    <members>Case.StopStartDate</members>
    <members>Case.Sub_category__c</members>
    <members>Case.Subject</members>
    ....
    <name>CustomField</name>

    ....
    <members>Case</members>
    .....
    <name>CustomObject</name>
```

And the version is 39.0
The error that we are getting with ant deploy is this one: 
"Case.Support   Business Process 95 24  Picklist value: On-Hold not found".
I have found this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YTOAA2 but not sure if it's related ?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: In your destination org, do you have access to the field ? Check sys admin profile.

Comment: Thanks SL man. Yes I do have accesss on the field and also checked  'Manage Cases' and 'Transfer Cases' and I have both of these permissions too.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Hi Richard, no we didn't manage to resolve this through the metadata. We had to go in the destination org and create the values manually and then deploy our whole package.

Answer (score 1):

This is years late but I was having the same problem and the answer is that standard picklist fields must be deployed through standardValueSets in the metadata API.

[Move standard picklist values using SFDX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215236/move-standard-picklist-values-using-sfdx)