# Picklist value: <value> in picklist: Type not found

Tags: salesforcedx

When doing `sfdx force:source:push` with Account RecordTypes, I'm getting a series of errors like this:

`productCatalog\main\default\objects\Account\recordTypes\AdvisorRep.recordType-meta.xml          Picklist value: Competitor in picklist: Type not found (15:18)`

The `Type` field is in the `AdvisorRep.recordType-meta.xml` file, and `Type` is a built in field.  So I don't understand what this error is trying to tell me.

AdvisorRep.recordType-meta.xml:

````xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecordType xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>AdvisorRep</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <label>Advisor (Rep)</label>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Industry</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Agriculture</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Apparel</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Banking</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Biotechnology</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Chemicals</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Communications</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Construction</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Consulting</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Education</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Electronics</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Energy</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Engineering</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Entertainment</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Environmental</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Finance</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Food %26 Beverage</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Government</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Healthcare</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Hospitality</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Insurance</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Machinery</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Manufacturing</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Media</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Not For Profit</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Other</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Recreation</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Retail</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Shipping</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Technology</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Telecommunications</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Transportation</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Utilities</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Ownership</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Other</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Private</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Public</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Subsidiary</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Rating</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Cold</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Hot</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Warm</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Type</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Competitor</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Event</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>IT</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Insurance</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Legal</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Other</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Securities</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Services</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Confidential</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
</RecordType>
```xml
````

Comment: I think that the value `Competitor` is what is missing

Comment: I added the meta xml above.  In the values list for `Type`, the first entry is `Competitor`

Comment: Make sure you are pushing against the correct API level. If too low, this field/value might not be defined.

Comment: I'm pushing this to a scratch org that I just created.

Comment: Make sure that the scratch org has all the correct features that you would expect - esp for this picklist. It could be that the api level is too high OR too low.

Comment: Try checking your Type field in the Account object metadata; make sure the Type field Label and Api Name are the same case, I sometimes got this error when my picklist label and api name had case difference, which is read as unique strings by metadata api (i.e.  "type" != "Type").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You receive this error because you added custom value to the standard picklist "Type" but your source directory missing following file:

> AccountType.standardValueSet-meta.xml

It should be placed under `force-app/main/default/standardValueSets` folder and look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Prospect</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Prospect</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Customer - Direct</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Customer - Direct</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Customer - Channel</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Customer - Channel</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Channel Partner / Reseller</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Channel Partner / Reseller</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Installation Partner</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Installation Partner</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Technology Partner</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Technology Partner</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Other</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Other</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Competitor</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Competitor</label>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>
```

Comment: This was the issue.  For anyone reading this in the future, SFDX doesn't automatically export custom values that have been added to a Standard Value Set.  So, you have to manually add an entry to your package.xml to add them.  You also can't wildcard the members.  
- [List of Standard Value Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm)  
- [How to add Standard Value Set to package.xml](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215236/move-standard-picklist-values-using-sfdx)

Comment: Custom values can be retrieved from Scratch orgs using sfdx force:source:pull command but not sfdx force:retrieve

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps anyone else, but we were getting this error on a specific record type. The value in question was on the "Type" field. The solution was to pull down and version control the "ObjectType" field, in our case it was a Task, so `retrieve -m 'StandardValueSet:TaskType'`

Answer (score 0):

I was having this difficulty too, but with this package I was able to deploy the values of the Case. Status:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Case.Ouvidoria</members>
        <name>BusinessProcess</name>
    </types> 
    <types> 
        <members>Case.Status</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types> 
    <types> 
        <members>CaseStatus</members>
        <name>StandardValueSet</name>
    </types>    
    <version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```